# Regex scrape the price without any tags

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to scrape the price like `1699.20` from `1'699.200`.

How can i do that via regex exp?

```
    Reservation source: Booking.com reservation #591064783

The following information was provided by Booking.com at the time the reservation was created:

    *** Reservation information ***
    Reservation made on: 2015-11-08 at 23:54:52
    Currency: EUR
    Total reservation amount: 1'699.200
    Total reservation commission amount: 254.880

    *** Customer information ***
    Name: Daniele
    Email: 677114@guest.booking.com
    Address: 
    Zip / Post code: 
    City: .
    Country: Switzerland
    Company: 
    Phone: +41761
    Remarks: Hello, we might be 9 friends, and we can bring our own mattress would it be a problem? If it is, then we will be 8.

    *** Room guest information ***
    Room arrival date: 2015-12-29
    Room departure date: 2016-01-02
    Check-in: 2015-12-29
    Check-out: 2016-01-02
    Guest name: Daniele
    Number of guests: 8
    Smoking preference: Non-smoking
    Remarks: 

    *** Room/facilities information ***
    Room facilities: Tea/Coffee maker, Shower, Hairdryer, Iron, Refrigerator, Desk, Ironing facilities, Sitting area, Fan, Toilet, Microwave, Washing machine, Bathroom, Heating, Kitchen, Flat-screen TV, Sofa, Hardwood/Parquet floors, Dining area, Electric kettle, Kitchenware, Wardrobe/Closet, Oven, Stovetop, Cleaning products, City view, Towels, Linens, Dining table, Private apartment in building, Clothes rack
    Room information: No meal is included in this room rate. Children and Extra Bed Policy: All children are welcome. One child under 3 years is charged EUR 10  per night in a crib. Any additional children under 4 years are charged  EUR 10 per night for extra beds. The maximum number of extra beds/cribs in a room is 1.  Deposit Policy: 20 percent of the total amount may be charged anytime after booking.  Cancellation Policy: Please note, if canceled or modified, 100 percent of the total price of the reservation will be charged.
    Room extra information: This apartment has a washing machine, seating area and oven.

    *** Room pricing information ***
    Currency: EUR
    Total price: 1'699.200
    Commission: 254.880
    Nightly prices:
     2015-12-29: 424.000 (rate: 4103701 "Standard Rate")
     2015-12-30: 424.000 (rate: 4103701 "Standard Rate")
     2015-12-31: 424.000 (rate: 4103701 "Standard Rate")
     2016-01-01: 427.200 (rate: 4103701 "Standard Rate")
```

Here is what i've tried, https://regex101.com/r/aE6vK0/1 but this is not it.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: PHP, but i am trying to accomplish it just via 1 expression like Total reservation amount:(\s+[^\s]+). so any working regex101 should do it

Comment: Once you got the "1'699.200" string, use your programming language to remove the quotes and simply convert to a number.

Comment: If you _always_ expect the format `Total reservation amount: ` followed by some amount, then you can simply extract everything after the colon.  Can you let us know what range of inputs you expect to have?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added the full template i am scraping the information from, and it comes always like this.

Comment: Try [`Total [^:\n]*\b(?:amount|price)\b[^:\n]*:\s+(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/zG9hS0/1).

Comment: @stribizhev Correct me if I'm way off, but couldn't he just match everything after the colon and then (attempt to) convert it into a number in his PHP script?  His problem seems to be more one of _extraction_ using regex, rather than validation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I just suggest to precise the price search. I do not understand the requirments, since they are not specified in the question. I would not dare to answer it, so good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use a single regular expression to sort through digits/non-digits, create a regular expression to match your context then use a callback function on the results array.

```
preg_match_all("~:\h*(\d+(?:['.]\d+)+)~", $str, $matches);

$results = 
   array_map(function($n) {
     return number_format(strtr($n, array("'"=>'')), 2, '.', '');
   }, $matches[1]);

print_r($results);
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/474276)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a PHP guru, but the comments already given seem to be a good direction.  For each template, you can simply run the following regex against each line:

```
Total reservation amount:\s(.*)
```

I will assume that the match above will be stored into a PHP variable called `$num`.  You can cast it to a `double` and then use it however you wish, e.g.

```
$num = 1'699.200;
$num = str_replace("'", "", $num);
$double_val = doubleval($num)
```

Since the templates you are scraping were themselves likely all generated by a (deterministic) computer program, you should not have to deal with random formats.  Rather, there should be a single set of formats which you can anticipate by having a look at a number of templates.

Comment: This seems good, however not sure what does the (double) do? not aware of such PHP function and incase this is a function i think it should look like double($num);

Comment: Try using the `doubleval()` function.  Since the template you are using was likely generated by a computer program, you should not have to worry much about unexpected formatting.

Comment: @IlanHasanov No, the function is an alias to `floatval()` and converts a value to a float (see the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php))